# How to make ng-hide and ng-show work on different section of the SPA?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am developing a SPA. In the side navigation I have added some buttons and when clicking those buttons I want the different content to be shown accordingly.

I realized that the ng-hide and show don't work because the buttons are on the header and the content to be shown is in the lower section.

Is there a workaround in this case ?

Comment: Did you try to use events for communicate via $rootScope or create main layout controller?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$emit` and `$broadcast` to communicate between child and parent scopes.

If you want to send a parameter to the child use `$broadcast`:

```
//in parent controller
$scope.$broadcast('someEvent', params) //send params to show/hide

//in child controller
$scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, args) {
    console.log(args) //the params will be in args, use them to show/hide
})
```

Similarly, use `$emit` if you want to communicate from the child scope to  the parent scope.

Comment: I actually fix it using ng-hide and ng-show but in this way:

`ng-click="show='a'"
ng-show="show=='a'" `

Answer (score 0):

I actually fix it using ng-hide and ng-show but in this way:

`<a class="tooltip-side-nav" href="#features"  ng-click="show='a'" data-placement="left"></a>`

`<h3 class="media-heading" ng-show="show=='a'">Hello</h3>`